# XIB Modal window ios

Tags: objective-c, xib

How to create a modal window in objective-c XIB window?
I have created a multiple columns table, now onclick of any row i.e on didSelectRowIndexPath event I want to open a modal window.

Answer (score 0):

When you select a Cell in your row. Define the view Controller you want to display in your Modal View.

```
YourViewController *vc = [[YourViewController alloc] initwithnibname:@"YourViewController" bundle:nil];
vc.(delegatemethod) = self;
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Comment: Hi, I did the above things in following steps:created the delegate by                                                      1)@protocol myViewControllerDelegate<NSObject>                    2) @property(nonatomic,weak)id<myViewControllerDelegate>delegate; 3)from my base controller ---  @interface        mybaseController:uiTableViewController<TableViewControllerDelegate>.                                                             Then in mybasecontroller i wrote the code above all went well it compiled but it dint steped into myViewController.

Comment: I need to see the code for this . Why don't you try debugging and check where is it stopping ??